# How to give row numbers based a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like

| City | Customer |
| --- | --- |
| Banglore | A |
| Banglore | B |
| Chennai | D |
| Chennai | F |
| Banglore | C |

I need to give the row numbers based on the city and Customer Count. Banglore has 3 customers and Chennai has 2

I need a result like

| City | Customer | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Banglore | A | 1 |
| Banglore | B | 2 |
| Banglore | C | 3 |
| Chennai | D | 1 |
| Chennai | F | 2 |

IS it possible to get this result?

Thanks

Comment: depends on your DB's version. If it's 8.0, then easily use window function `ROW_NUMBER()`, otherwise a bit daunting.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT C.CITY,C.CUSTOMER,
     ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY C.CITY ORDER BY C.CUSTOMER ASC)AS XCOL
 FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Could you please try this one